# How do I fix a system crash with WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR?

Tags: windows, bsod, minidumps

I'm getting a random `WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR`. Either happens when gaming, streaming and even when computer is idling. It doesn't seem to happen at a specific task.

I had the CPU replaced as well as my hard drive and my power supply. I tried every RAM stick independently. I formatted my computer more times than I can count. CPU temps goes between 25 - 60 depending on the load. I tried to trigger the error through various stress tests. Unfortunately there is no specific test that triggers the crash. I updated every single bios and drivers.

I don't really know how to interpret [the memory dumps generated by Windows](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1B7ZceeNyAiv_RO1YX5or304Oobskl_aA?usp=sharing).

My system:

- CPU: i9-9900k
- Motherboard: Aorus Z390 Xtreme rev.01
- GPU: Aorus RTX2080 Ti Xtreme
- RAM: 4x Kingston 16gb 3200MHz (KHX3200C16D4)
- PSU: Corsair RM850x

Answer (score 1):

The dump references pshed.dll which is an internal hardware error and may be tricky to nail down so that means motherboard or CPU. I used nirsoft.net Blue Screen View on the latest (by date / time) dump you left.

[Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/bsods-whea-uncorrectable-error-haldll-and-psheddll/4f28d68d-28ca-4a7f-89b7-1b5fd22e0ed8?auth=1)

> WHEA error usually means a hardware issue.
>
> This is an Internal unclassified error as inferred from the dump,
> getting to the root cause can be tough.
>
> Severity : Fatal
>
> Error : Internal unclassified (Proc 4 Bank 4) Status :
> 0xba00000011000402

At this point, given the error, I suggest you get the machine serviced and see if the repair shop can give you a workable answer.

One thing to try prior to taking it to the shop would be to make a bootable USB key for memtest86.exe and run several passes to test memory.

https://www.memtest86.com/

Comment: I already tried a memtest86 4 passes and returned with no error. I wanted to nail it down by myself. Not quite sure what a repair shop will do that I can't. If it is my motherboard, I'm done for...Gigabyte RMA is a pain and many have found themselves with no replies after sending defective parts..

Comment: @seb next step is to replace parts one by one to see which one is defective. Repair shop probably has spare parts, for you it's probably an unnecessary investment.

Comment: Not quite sure what a repair shop will do that I can't.   <-- They can possibly substitute parts and tell you which part to replace. I did assume you did not want to purchase all the replacements to see which one..